# Is there a way to disable iOS simulator's network during a UI automation test

Tags: swift, ui-automation, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I get many tests, which require no network state. Because all the tests will executed in CI so cannot use a real device.

Solutions I found from internet:

1. There is tool could be installed in Mac and control network status -> Cannot use for an automation test.
2. Use real device -> No, because all tests would be executed in CI and also include parallel, so simulator is better way.

After these failed attempts, I inject "noNetwork" as environment to the app like this minimum example. And return a "noNetwork" Error to API calls if this env exist in code.

```
// In test
envs["networkStatus"] = "noNetworkConnection"
launchEnvironment = envs

// In app code
if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["networkStatus"] == "noNetworkConnection" {
            completion(.failure(.noNetworkConnection))
        }
```

It block the Simulator's network but another problem is coming, because `launchEnvironment` takes effect when app is launched, and there is API calls during app launch, so these API calls also get blocked as no network.

My purpose is to reach to a certain step then disable the network. I'm wondering whether there is a way to inject the env or what ever to the app during a UI test? Appreciate for any help, guys.

Comment: You could stub out only the specific calls you want to block. Look into Swifter or Embassy. The latter is very lightweight.

Comment: Although the above isn’t the same as your device not having connectivity. This strikes me as one of those tests better left for being performed manually.

Comment: Thanks, good to know those libraries. And I figure out a way yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I find a way out, yesterday I totally re-consider how UI test interact with App, and the answer is UI interaction like button touch, pull to refresh, page opening, basically a user's action.

**Thus**, I create another global variable `shouldDisableNetwork` to control network connection together with injected env.

To do it, change this flag to true in some action code like button tap.

```
onSendButtonCompletion { [unowned self] in
    // For UI Test
    var shouldDisableNetwork = true
    ...
}
```

And now with two flags, when the button is tapped, `shouldDisableNetwork` become to true, then the network is disabled.

```
// In network call
        if ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["networkStatus"] == "noNetworkConnection" && shouldDisableNetwork {
            completion(.failure(.noNetworkConnection))
            return
        }
```

It is ok for a simple test, though one thing worth to mention that this is one way trip, no turn back, but I could set `shouldDisableNetwork` to false in some other UI action, which one doesn't require network connection.

Comment: Great solution! I generally don’t love modifying the app for the purpose of UI testing, but this seems innocent enough.

Comment: Yeah, me 2. I have came to XCTest world like 5 month and found a fact that there is alway some places I need to change the app code in order to make the test work. Like add accessibility identifier, inject mock date etc...